# pip broken after upgrading

Tags: python, bash, pip, easy-install

I did pip install -U easyinstall, and then pip install -U pip to upgrade my pip. However, I get this error now when trying to use pip:

```
root@d8fb98fc3a66:/# which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
root@d8fb98fc3a66:/# pip
bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

This is on an ubuntu 12.04 in a docker image.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall pip?

Comment: Yes, but that just leaves me with an un-updated version of pip...which starts this cycle again

Comment: Have you tried `easy_install pip`?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work. However, falsetru solved this issue. Will accept his answer when I can.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

One reason can be remembed locations.

You can clear the cached locations by issuing following command:

```
hash -r
```

SIDENOTE: Instead of `which`, using `type` command, you can see the hashed location:

```
$ type pip
pip is /usr/local/bin/pip
$ pip -V
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$ type pip
pip is hashed (/usr/local/bin/pip)
```

Answer (score 1):

If doing `hash -r` doesn't work, it's possible that the new `pip` got installed in `/usr/local/bin/` instead of the old one in `/usr/bin/`. And it so happens that the new location is not in the list of paths searched for executables.

In that case, **either** fix the list of paths **or** copy the executables:

```
cp -p /usr/local/bin/pip* /usr/bin/
```

You may also hardlink the executables instead of copying them (this may ensure that future upgrades are done correctly).