# Multiple problems with pip3, python3 and pygame

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to install pygame on my mac. I'm running OSX El Capitan 10.11.5. When i try installing pygame via pip3:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

It comes out with this error

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip3: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have checked that pip3 is actually installed by typing

```
which pip3 -version
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

I am at a total loss and it's confusing me quite a bit.. Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: This may help you although related to python 2.7 -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768128/pip-installation-usr-local-opt-python-bin-python2-7-bad-interpreter-no-such-f

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade pip and try

```
pip install -U pip
```

After install a virtualenv

```
pip install --ignore-installed virtualenvwrapper
```

Edit .bash_profile, in terminal write

```
echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> .bash_profile
```

Refresh bash_profile, in Terminal write `source .bash_profile`

Make a virtualenv and using python3

```
mkvirtualenv MyProject --python=python3
```

And go to your virtualenv

```
workon MyProject
```

Now install pygame from pip `pip install pygame` or `pip3 install pygame`