# scrapy installation fails with message 'bad interpreter: No such file or directory'

Tags: python, scrapy, pip

I use mac and I followed the steps on http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/intro/install.html. Everything goes fine until the last step:    pip install Scrapy
the error message is as follows

```
dyn-118-138-17-209:~ ff$    pip install Scrapy
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have installed both python2 and python3 and homebrew

result of which python

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

how to fix the problem, thanks!

Comment: can you post results of "which python"? Seems like pip can't find your python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51524564/6826127) worked for me, followed the first set of instructions explaining the 'fixing pip' and in the second part explaining 'fixing virtualenv', just replaced *virtualenv* with *scrapy*