# How to set python path with git bash in windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip, git-bash

Using Git Bash on Windows 10.

python version: 2.7.12

When run `pip`, it shows:

```
$ pip
bash: /c/cygwin/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How to find the right python path with pip?

---

## Addition

```
$ which python
/c/cygwin/bin/python
```

Comment: what do you see when you type `$ which python` ?

Comment: Ah, duplicate of this as far as I can tell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768128/pip-installation-usr-local-opt-python-bin-python2-7-bad-interpreter-no-such-f

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip installation /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768128/pip-installation-usr-local-opt-python-bin-python2-7-bad-interpreter-no-such-f)

Comment: @JacoblRR That's on mac, but this is on windows. They are very different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pip is somehow using the wrong path for your python that doesn't exist. However, there is a simple workaround, you can type this to specify the python interpreter you want to use:

```
$ /c/cygwin/bin/python -m pip install yourpackage
```

This is only a temporary workaround, to fix it, try something from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31768128/6622817) question.