# zsh: /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: no such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, youtube-dl

macOS 10.12

Seems like the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768128/pip-installation-usr-local-opt-python-bin-python2-7-bad-interpreter-no-such-f?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but top answers just led to more questions.

[Top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33872341/1757149) says to do:

`brew link --overwrite python`

which yields:

```
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5
To relink: brew unlink python && brew link python
```

I'm pretty sure I need to get homebrew to switch to 2.7 rather than using version 3. I do

`brew unlink python && brew link python`

and get:

```
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5... 25 symlinks removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5... 25 symlinks created
```

Is there a way I can tell it to link to a specific version? `/usr/local/Cellar/python/` contains: `2.7.13   2.7.14   2.7.14_3 3.6.3    3.6.5`

**How can I get my system to always use `2.7.14_3`?**

`/usr/local/opt/python/bin` contains `python3`, `python3-config`, and 3.6 versions. How can I get 2.7 in here and remove 3 and 3.6?

Also `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`. When I type `python -V` I get `Python 2.7.10`. `/usr/bin` contains `python2.7`, `python2.7-config` as well as some other seemingly-python-related things (but no python3, which is good I think). Is this different from homebrew pythons? Thanks in advance.

*Edit:*

[Second-to-top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31769149/1757149) says to do `head -n1 /usr/local/bin/pip` which returns

`head: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory`

and

`mv /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip.old`

returns

`mv: rename /usr/local/bin/pip to /usr/local/bin/pip.old: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python` (you might not want to `--ignore dependencies` depending on what other things you might be breaking, i.e. numpy, opencv)
2. `brew install python@2` [see here](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/python-2-problem/1888)
3. `brew uninstall youtube-dl`
4. `brew install youtube-dl`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to use `pyenv` to manage Python versions, and then use `python3 -m pip install -U yt-dlp` to install `yt-dlp` into `` ~/.pyenv/versions/`cat ~/.pyenv/version`/bin ``.