# Getting "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directo" when running S3 command on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I'm using Mac High Sierra.  I'm tryhign to install Amazon's S3 cli tools.  I thought I had installed successfully through pip, but then I got this error tryihng to run an s3 command ...

```
localhost:~ davea$ s3cmd --recursive ls s3://sbdasset.springboardonline.com | grep "resource"
-bash: /usr/local/bin/s3cmd: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Per the answer here -- [pip installation /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768128/pip-installation-usr-local-opt-python-bin-python2-7-bad-interpreter-no-such-f), I tried the recommendation ...

```
localhost:~ davea$ brew link --overwrite python
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2
To relink: brew unlink python && brew link python
```

However, then I re-ran the above command and got the same error.  None of the other answers in that SO post worked.  What else do I need ot check install to get Amazon's S3 cli tools working?

Comment: what do you get with python --version?

Comment: That gives me "Python 3.7.2"

Comment: Side-note: These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and ran `brew upgrade s3cmd`

It did the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

try to open a new terminal and run s3cmd, it maybe env variables missing if not working do one of the following:
try to reinstall python

```
brew install python@2
```

or install Anaconda
https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#macos
then open a new terminal window and try again it should work

Comment: Hi, I actually already have Python 3.7 installed.  When I run "which python," it gives me "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/python"

Comment: s3cmd does't see it right "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"
it is trying to do python2.7.
you can install Anaconda and it will overwrite env variables and have your env fixed or you can try to fix it manually
unlink /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/python

Comment: When I run "unlink /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7" I got a file not found error.  What's the intention there?  You want me to unlink Python 2.7 whereever it is installed in my /usr/local dir?

Comment: yep, but obviously, it is not installed, probably you have it set up in your .bashrc file, check it out that it is not in path otherwise why s3cmd is trying to use it.
why don't u install conda it will solve the issue.

Comment: Point of clarity -- is anachonda the same thing as Python 3.7?  Per our other question, I do get "Python 3.7" printed out when I run "python --version"

Comment: Anaconda will reinstall python and fix your env var issue.

Comment: thank you @dmitry , helped me tremendously: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59774110/201657