# Python script not running : -bash: ./btltest.py: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, postgresql, macos

I have a python script that establishes connection to postgres db and writes results in csv.

When I run it from terminal on Mac, using command

```
administrators-MacBook-Pro:ml bob$ ./btltest.py -d dev -u temp_viewer -p "xxxxxxx" -l debug -s "2019-08-10" -e "2019-08-20"
```

it shows error

```
-bash: ./btltest.py: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Using same credentials i.s. pass, user, db name as in the code to connect through pgadmin4 has no problem.

How can I remove this error ?

Comment: Your program can't find the Python interpreter. There could be a broken symbolic link. Run the command `which python3` or `which python` to show the path to the python3 executable. Are you in a virtual environment?

Comment: no, local machine. the command outputs '/usr/local/bin/python3
'

Comment: I see. This means that your python exe is under local path and the program looks for is under global /user/bin/python3. You have to create a symbolic link

Comment: @JuliaK: this command take to bin

Comment: @JuliaK: can you please help how ?

Comment: Try setting the link: `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: ln: /usr/local/bin/python3: File exists

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768128/pip-installation-usr-local-opt-python-bin-python2-7-bad-interpreter-no-such-f

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200082/discussion-between-julia-k-and-xceptable).

Comment: Try `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3`,

Comment: @defense2000x: administrators-MacBook-Pro:~ bob$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3
ln: /usr/bin/python3: Operation not permitted

Comment: Ah, that's Apple's System Integrity Protection chiming in... I have it disabled on my machine.... I guess it would be easier to just change the first line in your `btltest.py`script to something like `#!/usr/bin/env python3` (*if* your script starts with `#!/usr/bin/python3`)